# Error failed to load a view in SAPUI5 since today

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

I had created a table in SAPUI5 using ODATA services. And it worked perfectly fine until today. Today the HTML file loads a blank page and when i check the developer tools, I see the following error:

```
Failed to load resource http://hana_server_name:4000/ui_test/ui5_test/WebContent/ui5_test/VisitorData.view.js
Uncaught Error: failed to load 'ui5_test/VisitorData.view.js' from ./ui5_test/VisitorData.view.js: 0 - NetworkError: A network error occurred.
```

The ODATA service is working fine, and I'm using the same ODATA file to create a chart, and the chart renders as normal.
I'm getting the same error message for 2 tables that I've created.
It looks like this is caused by some changes to the server but I'm not sure what changed or if its a problem with my code. If its a server error, what should i be looking for.

Thank you,
Salman

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty obvious, isn't it? Your view `VisitorData.view.js` was simply not found and therefore can not load. Did you check if it is physically available on the server? Missing file permissions could be another reason.

You can also check
http://hanaservername.com:4000/ui_test/ui5_test/WebContent/resources/ to see a listing of the deployed sources (if your application/server is configured to allow that). On Java Application Servers (local Tomcat, Java Stack, no clue what HANA uses...) you need to set the following in your web.xml:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sap.ui5.resource.DEV_MODE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Comment: I get a 404 - Not found. How do I enable this site?

Comment: Haven't used it on a HANA System. If you have a web.xml you need to enabled dev mode. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i consider you are binding data which you get from server to your table or chart.
Even if server didn't give you the data your code should work properly without giving any error, so i suppose problem should be in your code.
Just run your code with debug mode ON on your browser and click on error thrown by browser and it will lead you to the line which is causing the error